# Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

I already tried everything that I could think of, but my net.tcp service just can't be accessed.
[image: This is the endpoint in my web.config]
[image: This is my IIS service "site"]
[image: And this is the error in the WCF Test Client]

The full error message in the WCF Test Client: Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost:807/ClienteService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the [MSDN documentation (Publishing Metadata)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455). WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: net.tcp://localhost:807/ClienteService.svc    O metadados cont‚m uma referˆncia que nÆo pode ser resolvida: 'net.tcp://localhost:807/ClienteService.svc'.    NÆo foi poss¡vel ativar o servi‡o solicitado, 'net.tcp://localhost:807/ClienteService.svc'. Consulte os logs de rastreamento de diagn¢stico do servidor para obter mais informa‡äes.

I already tried to check the net.tcp listener.
Checked the IIS Site
Checked the local files
Changed net.tcp port to another number such as 506
Tried other endpoints to another service

Comment: First you need to make sure has enabled net.tcp at site and server level. Your screenshoot doesn't show that which level you enabled. So it's better check again. Then you have two ways to publish metadata. First is code, if you publish through code, use try catch to capture the error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-code  If you publish through configuration file, make sure baseaddr is right.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-publish-metadata-for-a-service-using-a-configuration-file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.